# postgres - comparing two arrays

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

postgres has an array data type, in this case a numeric array:

```
CREATE TABLE sal_emp (name text, pay_by_quarter integer[]);
INSERT INTO sal_emp VALUES ('one', '{1,2,3}');
INSERT INTO sal_emp VALUES ('two', '{4,5,6}');
INSERT INTO sal_emp VALUES ('three', '{2,4,6}');
SELECT * FROM sal_emp;

Result:
one, {1,2,3}
two, {4,5,6}
three, {2,4,6}
```

From what i can tell, you can only query an array as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM sal_emp WHERE 4=ANY(pay_by_quarter);
SELECT * FROM sal_emp WHERE ARRAY[4,5,6]=pay_by_quarter;
```

which means you can select a row with the array contains a match for a single argument, or if the whole array matches an array argument.

I need to select a row where any member of the row's array matches any member of an argument array - kind of like an 'IN' but i can't figure out how. I've tried the following two approaches but neither work:

```
SELECT * from sal_emp WHERE ARRAY[4,5,6]=ANY(pay_by_quarter);
SELECT * from sal_emp WHERE ANY(pay_by_quarter) IN (4,5,6);
```

I assume i could do something with converting the array to a string but that sounds like poor solution..

any ideas?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

figured it ... there's an && operator

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html

"&&     overlap (have elements in common)   ARRAY[1,4,3] && ARRAY[2,1]"

Answer (score 13):

For comparing arrays in Postgress, there are array operators.
Find the Operators section here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html

**A quick way to compare two arrays is by doing so,**

```
( (ARRAY_1 @> ARRAY_2) AND (ARRAY_1 <@ ARRAY_2) )
```

which basically checks if all the unique values in ARRAY_2 is present in ARRAY_1 `AND` vice versa.
Don't forget to use both the checks/conditions/comparison in conjunction(`AND`)

These are called containment operators which checks all the **unique** values in one array and compares it with the other. They are also called as bird-operators because the operator `@>` AND `<@` resembles the head of a bird.

The way it works is as follows:

```
ARRAY_1 <@ ARRAY_2
// Check/Direction: Left-to-Right
// Checks if all the unique elements in ARRAY_1 is present in ARRAY_2 as well. If yes, it will return TRUE
// Please note this will return TRUE even if ARRAY_2 has extra elements that are not present in ARRAY_1
```

Similarly,

```
ARRAY_1 @> ARRAY_2
// Note we have changed the operator to '@>' from '<@'. Check/Direction: Right-to-Left
// Checks if all the unique elements in ARRAY_2 is present in ARRAY_1 as well. If yes, it will return TRUE
// Please note this will return TRUE even if ARRAY_1 has extra elements that are not present in ARRAY_2
```

**So even if the order of elements are different it, will still work.**

A simple way to not get confused and remember this is by looking at the `>` OR `<` sign.
The ARRAY(unique elements) which has the less-than sign pointed is being compared with the ARRAY(unique elements) with greater-than sign pointed.
So the ARRAY which has the greater-than sign pointed can contain extra unique elements, and still return `TRUE`.

Let us try some examples

```
SELECT array[1, 2, 3] @> array[1, 2, 3] AS RESULT
!-- Returns TRUE (Check is Right-to-Left)

SELECT array[1, 2, 3] @> array[3, 1, 2] AS RESULT
!-- Returns TRUE (Check is Right-to-Left)

SELECT array[1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3] @> array[1, 2, 3] AS RESULT
!-- Returns TRUE (Check is Right-to-Left)

SELECT array[1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3] <@ array[3, 2, 1, 3, 2, 5] AS RESULT
!-- Returns TRUE (Check is Left-to-Right)

SELECT array[1, 2, 3, 4] <@ array[1, 2, 3] AS RESULT
!-- Returns FALSE (Check is Left-to-Right)

SELECT array[1, 2, 3, 4] @> array[1, 2, 3] AS RESULT
!-- Returns TRUE (Check is Right-to-Left)

SELECT array[1, 2, 3] <@ null AS RESULT
!-- Returns empty (Check is Left-to-Right)

SELECT array[1, 2, 3] @> null AS RESULT
!-- Returns empty (Check is Right-to-Left)

SELECT null <@ null AS RESULT
!-- Doesn't work if both the values are null - Error: Operator is not unique: unknown <@ unknown

SELECT array[1, 2, 3] <@ array[] AS RESULT
!-- Doesn't work on empty arrays - Error: Cannot determine type of empty array

SELECT array[] <@ array[] AS RESULT
!-- Doesn't work on empty arrays - Error: Cannot determine type of empty array
```

**Please note**

- This is used for comparing arrays.
- Works by extracting unique values from both the arrays - and then compares them.
- It does not check the count of elements in the ARRAY. i.e it can return TRUE even if both the arrays are of different length (`[1, 2] @> [1]` OR `[1, 1] @> [1]` are still `TRUE`)
- Doesn't work if both the values are `NULL`
- Doesn't work if either of the array is empty (`[]`)

Answer (score 6):

To compare elements of an array with elements of another array for at least one match you can use `&&` operator. It will return true only if at least one element from each array match.

Though right answer to this question is already here for decades I am adding this example for better clarity to beginners.

Schema:

```
 create table mytable (id int, value text[]);
 insert into mytable values (1,'{"dog", "cat", "fish"}');
 insert into mytable values (2,'{"elephant", "mouse"}');
 insert into mytable values (3,'{"lizard", "dog", "parrot"}');
 insert into mytable values (4,'{"bear", "bird", "cat"}');
```

Query:

```
 select * from mytable where array['dog', 'cat']&&(value);
```

Output:

| id | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | {dog,cat,fish} |
| 3 | {lizard,dog,parrot} |
| 4 | {bear,bird,cat} |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=bfd363cc4a2656780be32ebc0d1920a9)*

Query#2 (match array element using wildcard characters)

To compare array elements using wildcard characters you can use unnest()  parse every element of both arrays and compare them using Like operator.

```
   SELECT    distinct m.*
   FROM  mytable m, unnest(value)b 
   inner join  unnest(array['dog%', 'ca%']) a 
   on b LIKE a
```

Output:

| id | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | {dog,cat,fish} |
| 3 | {lizard,dog,parrot} |
| 4 | {bear,bird,cat} |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=6108192d7d416ab2f68683df57b1f7f4)*

Comment: can we use something with wildcards like  `select * from mytable where array['dog%', '%cat%']&&(value); `?

Comment: It won't work that way. I have added another answer for this. Please check @soung

Answer (score 2):

Trying not to plagiarise pstanton's answer, but clarifying a use case.

To have a condition that is satisfied by *any* of two (or more) columns having any of a list of values:

```
 select * from mytable
 where array(col1, col2) && array('foo', 'bar', baz')
```

Comment: what about finding the values in the array *not* in the columns searched?

Comment: @thedigitalmouse you should ask that as a new question.