# Preparing where clause on JSON type columns in PostgreSQL

Tags: php, json, postgresql

I have a table containing students details, and a column in it will be containing the favorite colors of students in json array

```
-----------------------------------------------------
id   name                              colors
-----------------------------------------------------
1 John                                {'red','blue'}
2 Cena                                {'red'}
3 Templeman                           {'orange'}
4 Kristy                              {'pink','red'}
------------------------------------------------------
```

now I want to list all the students who are having one of these favorite colors

```
select  all students  whose colors IN (red,pink)
```

so the list I expect is

```
1 John                                {'red','blue'}
2 Cena                                {'red'}
4 Kristy                              {'pink','red'}
```

is there a way of making this? I tried searching individual color with `(color=red OR color = pink)`  but that makes the query long and causes delay when the matching list is huge, I think `IN` like color IN (red,pink) would do better than that, is that possible to search on json array column?

Comment: Use `&&` operator. Like in this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1647385/postgres-comparing-two-arrays):
`SELECT * FROM students where colors && '{"red"}' ;`

Comment: that didnt work, but a different one, just added my own answer

Comment: Oh, I see. Your `colors` described like text field. I tested query exactly on array: 
`CREATE TABLE students (id serial primary key, name varchar, color varchar[]);
INSERT INTO students (name, colors) VALUES 
 ('John', '{"red","blue"}'),
 ('Cena', '{"red"}'),
 ('Templeman', '{"orange"}'),
 ('Kristy', '{"pink", "red"}');
SELECT * FROM students where colors && '{"red"}' ;
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it finally

```
SELECT * FROM students where colors::jsonb ?| '{"red","pink"}' ;
```

so this fetches all records having any of the colors in their favorite column

?| is for any one matching element in the array, and ?& for all elements