# PostgresSQL: Getting number of correspondences between two arrays

Tags: arrays, postgresql

I want to compare and get number of corresposndeces between two arrays in PostgresSQL.

For example:
given the table

| id | array |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a, b, d |
| 2 | a, e |
| 3 | a, b, d, e |
| 4 | b, c, d |

I would like to obtain a comparison table:

| id_1 | id_2 | number_of_matches |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 1 | 3 | 3 |
| 1 | 4 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 | 2 |
| 2 | 4 | 0 |
| 3 | 4 | 2 |

There is no repeated values in each array, and the order of items inside arrays does not matter.

I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1647385/postgres-comparing-two-arrays) about the overlap operator (&&) but it only returns a boolean if there is or not any correspondence between two arrays, but not the number of correspondences.

```
CREATE TABLE data (id integer, val text[]);
INSERT INTO data VALUES (1, '{a,b,d}');
INSERT INTO data VALUES (2, '{a,e}');
INSERT INTO data VALUES (3, '{a,b,d,e}');
INSERT INTO data VALUES (4, '{b,c,d}');
SELECT a.id id_1, b.id id_2, a.val && b.val match 
FROM data a, data b
WHERE a.id < b.id;
```

returns

| id_1 | id_2 | match |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | t |
| 1 | 3 | t |
| 1 | 4 | t |
| 2 | 3 | t |
| 2 | 4 | f |
| 3 | 4 | t |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_15&fiddle=0c8a511af6396bbcc7dc82c873a41fa0)

```
WITH normalized AS (                      -- 2
    SELECT
        id,
        unnest(val) as array_element      -- 1
    FROM data
)
SELECT
    n1.id,
    n2.id,
    COUNT(*)
FROM normalized n1
JOIN normalized n2                        -- 3
    ON (n1.array_element = n2.array_element AND n1.id <> n2.id)
GROUP BY n1.id, n2.id                     -- 4
ORDER BY n1.id, n2.id
```

1. Normalize your data (note: You should think about normalizing your data directly in the table; means: no arrays) by creating one row per array element
2. Use a CTE to "store" your normalized result
3. Self-join your normalized result (but not the same `id`s) at the `array_element`
4. `GROUP` and `COUNT`

Comment: Normalizing data directly on table is always a good practice on SQL, but at this time would imply on needs for changes on aplication source code. My search for a solution using array was trying to avoid change costs.
This solution, normalizing data before, got better performance.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sobBPcfXY7h8j7y6tKXfDj/0

get the intersection of the 2 arrays an count the elements of it:

```
 SELECT 
   data.id,
   data2.id as id2,
   data.val,
   data2.val val2,
   ARRAY( SELECT * FROM UNNEST( data.val ) WHERE UNNEST = ANY( data2.val )) as intersection,
   cardinality(ARRAY( SELECT * FROM UNNEST( data.val ) WHERE UNNEST = ANY( data2.val ))) as number_of_matches
   from data,data as data2
 where data.id <> data2.id
```